# How to redirect a page in a site to another page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get a url to be redirected to another site. 
For eg. www.abc.com/joe needs to be redirected to www.xyz.com/joe

where www.abc.com is a wordpress site.

thanks

Prady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at the web server level; WordPress isn't involved. Add to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/?joe$ http://www.xyz.com/joe [R=301,L]
```

After the "RewriteEngine On" line that's already there because of WordPress.

Comment: Would this redirect all the url which has exact word "joe" after abc.com to http://www.xyz.com/joe ?

Comment: Also, is there anyway i could keep the url still as abc.com/joe?

Comment: Yes to your first question, no to your second, unless you don't redirect at all and instead have a page with a 100% size frame pointing to xyz.com/joe. But that is not usually something you want to do. It breaks the ability to bookmark anything reached inside the frame, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this answer I wrote over at SO's sister site [**WordPress Answers**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) to be helpful. In short you can **use PHP and a WordPress hook to do the redirection** which keeps you from having to mess with `.htaccess` and gives you a lot more control over what happens as well:

- [**Creating 301 Redirects for Post, Page, Category and Image URLs?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/creating-301-redirects-for-post-page-category-and-image-urls/1023#1023)

Hope this helps.

-Mike